# rewrite .htaccess code work with subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

creating Short URL script
when i use my script with any subdomain[like http://s.yourdomain.com] then .htaccess won't work but script work fine at other location like yourdomain.com/sh/

Here's Code that i write .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?short=$1
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

want .htaccess code that work on subdomain also
and do above functions

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^ http://s.yourdomain.com
```

Here you wil pass your sub domain name same as when we redirect url on mobile website. http://m.yourdomain.com